# OData query is very slow - how to speed up or pinpoint where the performance hit is?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

Odata queries seem to be extremely slow.

When I run SQL Profiler, a query I execute via OData (which selects the top 20 records) takes less than a second to execute. However, it can take up to 45sec for the data to be returned to the browser.

Is there anyway to speed this up or pinpoint where the performance hit is?

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData Version 7.0.0 - this is a **.NET Core** package

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve]

Comment: [Response Compression Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression) might help.

Answer (score -2):

since there are a few things you did not clarify, I'm going to assume on 1 or 2 things. I'm assuming you have a .net core web api that is exposing the odata service/connection to the database. I'm fairly certain on that and that part is probably fine for your back end as long as there are not any fun things happening such as a crazy amount of joins or you are not loading the entire database in memory.

You could check too if your internet is just that slow? Maybe really just bad wifi.

The other thing to check is to make sure the problem is not just your client code making calls elsewhere for other data or maybe you are doing a bunch of crazy mapping from your api objects to some sort of view. I would open up a browser such as chrome and use the inspection tools to see the network section and observe as the data loads how long the api calls take and then how long the client takes to download and maybe how long it takes to transform the data.

Good Luck!